# Butterknife NullPointerException with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-tablayout, butterknife

I have an activity with a `TabLayout` inside.
When not using Butterknife it works well.
But when using Butterknife, it show error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

**DetailActivity.java**

```java
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_USER = "extra_user";

    @BindView(R.id.tabs) TabLayout tabs;
    @BindView(R.id.view_pager) ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        // When using this, the application work well
        // ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        // TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    }
}
```

My Gradle(app)

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
```

Edit:
**activity_detail.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the layout also

Comment: I've edit my post. Please check

Comment: I've never used Butterknife, but don't you need to call `ButterKnife.bind(this);` right after the `setContentView()` call?

Comment: Its working. I forgot to call that